# Node.js tcp connection

Tags: node.js, tcp, promise

How to send "End" message after resolving promise? Sometimes I can send 2 "end" messages out of 4, sometimes 3. Files from FTP are being downloaded and it's ok. The only thing that doesn't work is sending "end" message after downloading a file. Do you have any idea why this code doesn't work properly?

This code was updated:

```js
const ftp = require("jsftp");
const fs = require("fs");
const net = require("net");
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp");

class ftpCredentials {
  constructor(host) {
    this.user = "xxx";
    this.pass = "xxx";
    this.host = host;
  }
}

const downloadFromFTP = (credentials, file) => {
  const client = new ftpCredentials(credentials.host);
  const ftpClient = new ftp(client);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let buf = null;
    ftpClient.get(file, (err, stream) => {
      if (!err && typeof stream !== "undefined") {
        // Events
        stream.on("data", (data) => {
          if (buf === null) buf = new Buffer(data);
          else buf = Buffer.concat([buf, data]);
        });
        stream.on("close", (err) => {
          if (err) rej("FILE_ERROR");
          const actualPath = `${credentials.path}/${file}`;
          fs.writeFile(actualPath, buf, "binary", (err) => {
            if (err) rej(err);
            ftpClient.raw("quit", (err, data) => {
              if (err) rej(err)
              res(file);
            });
          });
        });
        // Resume stream
        stream.resume();
      } else {
        rej("STREAM_ERROR");
      }
    });
  })
}

const handleSavingFile = (credentials, filesOnFTP) => {
  mkdirp(credentials.path, () => {
    fs.readdir(credentials.path, (err, fileNames) => {
      if (err) return err;
      const needToConnectToFTP = filesOnFTP.filter(name => fileNames.indexOf(name) !== -1).length === 0;
      const socketForEndMsg = net.createConnection(18005, credentials.host, () => {
        Promise.all(filesOnFTP.map((file) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // The problem is here:
            const socketWrite = socketForEndMsg.write(`End|ftp://${credentials.host}/${file}`, "UTF16LE");
            resolve(socketWrite);
            // Events
            socketForEndMsg.on("error", () => {
              console.log("Problem with sending End message!");
              reject();
            });
          });
        })).then(() => {
          socketForEndMsg.end();
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      });
    })
  })
}


const getScheme = (credentials) => {
  const socketForData = net.createConnection(18005, credentials.host, () => socketForData.write("Scheme", "UTF16LE"));
  // Events
  socketForData.on("close", () => console.log("TCP Connection closed"));
  socketForData.on("error", err => console.log(err));
  socketForData.on("data", (data) => {
    socketForData.end();

    const toUTF16Format = Buffer.from(data).toString("UTF16LE");
    const arrayFromTCPMessage = toUTF16Format.split(/\||;/);
    const filteredImages = arrayFromTCPMessage.filter(item => item.startsWith("scheme"))
    const isOK = arrayFromTCPMessage[0] === "OK";

    if (isOK) {
      handleSavingFile(credentials, filteredImages);
    }
  })
}

module.exports = getScheme;
```

```
Error message: Error: This socket is closed
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:722:18)
at Socket._write (net.js:782:8)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:407:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:393:5)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
at Promise (xxx\getScheme.js:56:29)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Promise.all.filesOnFTP.map (xxx\getScheme.js:54:18)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Socket.net.createConnection (xxx\getScheme.js:52:32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that, you like to listen to `error` event & that made you to use `Promise` to catch the error. But, the placement of the `error` event handler registration is wrong, as it is inside `.map` function call. So, `error` event will be registered number of times of `filesOnFTP` length.

I've moved that error handler to next line & using `writable` flag to see, if the socket is still writable before writing to it. I have also added few more event handlers, which will give you more information about the socket status(for debugging, you can remove them later).

```
const handleSavingFile = (credentials, filesOnFTP) => {
  mkdirp(credentials.path, () => {
    fs.readdir(credentials.path, (err, fileNames) => {
      if (err) return err;
      const needToConnectToFTP = filesOnFTP.filter(name => fileNames.indexOf(name) !== -1).length === 0;
      const socketForEndMsg = net.createConnection(18005, credentials.host, () => {
        for(let file of filesOnFTP) {
            // Before write to socket, check if it is writable still! 
            if(socketForEndMsg.writable) {
                socketForEndMsg.write(`End|ftp://${credentials.host}/${file}`, "UTF16LE");
            }
            else {
                console.log('Socket is not writable! May be closed already?');
            }
        }
      });

      // This is the correct place for the error handler!
      socketForEndMsg.on("error", (error) => {
        console.log("Problem with sending End message!", error);
      });

      socketForEndMsg.on("close", () => {
        console.log("Socket is fully closed!");
      });

      socketForEndMsg.on("end", () => {
        console.log("The other end of the socket has sent FIN packet!");
      });

    });

  });

}
```

Let me know if this works!

Thanks!

Comment: It helped me to find a problem!

Comment: What was the issue? Just curious!

Comment: It was not my fault. The second app is written in C#, is synchronous and couldn't handle many messages at once. I've used setTimeout for each of them and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wait for `connection` event on `socketForEndMsg` and then start sending your data

```
const handleSavingFile = (credentials, filesOnFTP) => {
    mkdirp(credentials.path, () => {
        fs.readdir(credentials.path, (err, fileNames) => {
            if (err) return err;
            const needToConnectToFTP = filesOnFTP.filter(name => fileNames.indexOf(name) !== -1).length === 0;
            const socketForEndMsg = net.createConnection(18005, credentials.host);
            socketForEndMsg.on('connect', () => {
                Promise.all(filesOnFTP.map((file) => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        // The problem is here:
                        const socketWrite = socketForEndMsg.write(`End|ftp://${credentials.host}/${file}`, "UTF16LE");
                        resolve(socketWrite);
                        // Events
                        socketForEndMsg.on("error", () => {
                            console.log("Problem with sending End message!");
                            reject();
                        });
                    });
                })).then(() => {
                    socketForEndMsg.end();
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Didn't help. I have an error: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Comment: Should be `filteredImages.map` not `filteredImages.forEach`, my mistake

Comment: socketForEndMsg is not defined now

Comment: Why you create connection for every image? You can't create one before loop?

Comment: Still can't send end message every time... I will put all my code

Comment: Maybe problem is with `End` in `End|ftp://${credentials.host}/${file}`. What this is doing? Or maybe server you are connected to disconnects after message